# Rails Alias route - invalid route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

**The Situation:** For Testimonials the user can create separate URL aliases these are saved in the table Testimonial.

So I've created the following route at the end of my routes file:

```
get '*alias', to: 'testimonial#show', as: 'testimonial_show'
```

This redirects to the testimonial controller show where I fetch the correct testimonial

**The Problem:**
Normally when I enter the url www.example.com/jobs it redirects to the correct jobs page but with the above (alias) line added it tries to redirect to to the testimonial controller instead of the jobs.

This is my route:

```
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

  # get "custom_page/testimonials"
  match '/404', :to => 'home#not_found'
  match '/422', :to => 'home#rejected'
  match '/500', :to => 'home#server_error'

  # resource :testimonial, :only => :index
  get "testimonial", to: 'testimonial#index', as: 'testimonial_index'
  get "testimonial/:id", to: 'testimonial#show', as: 'testimonial_show'
  get "video_testimonial/:id", to: 'testimonial#show_video', as: 'video_testimonial_show'
  get '/robots.txt' => 'home#robots'
  get "custom_page/evp"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :passwords => "passwords" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/users" => "registrations#new"
    get "/users/password", to: "passwords#create"
  end

  as :user do
    get "/login" => "home#index", :as => "new_user_session"
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end


  # User created pages
  resources :pages, :only => :show
  resources :jobs, :only => [:show, :index, :create] do
    resources :apply, :only => [:index, :create]
    resources :share, :only => [:index, :create]
  end

  get "/quick_sign_in" => "quick_sign_in#index"

  resources :apply, :only => :index do
    collection { get 'add'}
  end

  namespace :user do
    resource :profile, :only => [:show, :destroy, :update] do
      get "remove", :on => :member
      resources "attachments"

      collection { get 'add_attachment'}
    end
    resources :applications, :only => [:index, :destroy] do
      get "correspondence", :on => :collection
    end
    resources :jobs, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
  end

  root :to => 'home#index'
  get '*alias', to: 'testimonial#show', as: 'testimonial_show'
```

**EDIT 1:** Visit the jobs pages, when I visit www.example.com/jobs with the global matcher added I get the following :

```
No route matches {:controller=>"testimonial", :action=>"show", :id=>1, :locale=>:en}
```

**Edit 2:** The log without the SQL part:

```
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200] Started GET "/jobs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200]   Rendered jobs/_search_sidebar.html.erb (4.3ms)
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200]   Rendered jobs/_jobs.html.erb (2.3ms)
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200]   Rendered jobs/_testimonial.html.erb (3.6ms)
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200]   Rendered jobs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (200.6ms)
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 515.2ms
[2014-06-10 09:37:08 +0200]
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"testimonial", :action=>"show", :id=>1, :locale=>:en}):
  app/views/jobs/_testimonial.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_jobs__testimonial_html_erb__481122295330206577_70303349814440'
  app/views/jobs/index.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_jobs_index_html_erb__1584069629091687413_70303340318260'
```

**Edit 3: rake routes | grep job** 
[image]

Comment: also o/p for rake routes | grep job ??  , you have a namespace user, what is o/p for www.example.com/user/jobs

Comment: @GhostRider please notice edit 3.

Comment: the urls for /jobs are generated correctly, try to fix the issue in the views which point to a wrong url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two named routes called 'testimonial_show'

You should change the second one (the globbed one) to something else...

```
get '*alias', to: 'testimonial#show', as: 'testimonial_glob_show'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jobs page is trying to render a `testimonials` partial on line 17, and inside that partial (on line 14) is an invalid route to a testimonial that doesn't exist.